# Ubuntu 18.04 abiword - Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

Tags: 18.04, abiword

I have a vps with LEMP provided by digitalocean and when I am attempting to convert any pdf file to doc file I always get this error:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

** (abiword:2048): WARNING **: 17:08:51.861: clutter failed 0, get a life.
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
No DISPLAY: this may not be what you want.
```

I used this command:

```
abiword --to=doc file.pdf
```

And even when I type `abiword` alone I get the same error

Of course I don't have GUI on my vps, so maybe this is an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abiword seems to need an X server to convert things, even without causing any obvious windows to appear.

You could try setting up a dummy X server, or maybe SSHing in from a client with a GUI.

On Linux you could try `ssh -X`, or on Windows, Xming/PuTTY has worked for me in similar cases, as long as you enable X11 forwarding (in Connection -> SSH -> X11).